# Proposed table structure for user to get updates from his followed colleges

Tags: mysql

I have a scenario where users and colleges are registered,and student can follow any college.

What i need is to provides user with notification anytime college has any update.

I have following tables

```
Users
    id,name
Colleges
    id,name
Followers
    id,user_id,college_id

//What i am thinking to make a new table for updates

Updates
    //How to manage this stuff
```

Comment: What is your actual question?  Your current choice of 3 tables is canonical and looks good to me.  As for the other "stuff," tell us what it is and maybe someone can help you.

Comment: Suppose i have followed a college ABC,I want to get notification,whenever there is any update is ABC college sections

Comment: Notifications are the realm of software, not databases.  What is your actual question?

Comment: Suppose a college has a new announcement for admission,i want to store it in db but not real time notifications,so when user will refresh his page,he will get update about the new admission for specific college.

Comment: in simple wording i have a what's new page,where i will get updates from colleges that i have followed.Hope you will understand the scenario. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Your question is way too broad as it stands now.

Comment: so you need more details @TimBiegeleisen